# JSON load/dump in Python

Tags: python, json

From the docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

```
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

I modified it like this:

```
>>> the_dump=json.dumps("['foo', {'bar':['baz', null, 1.0, 2]}]")
>>> the_load = json.loads(the_dump)
u"['foo', {'bar':['baz', null, 1.0, 2]}]"
```

Now it's a string. I want to do this: `the_load[1]['bar']`.

Can it be done this way? Where am I going wrong?

Why does this work?

```
>>> a= "[1,2,3]"
>>> json.loads(a)[0]
1
```

Comment: If you're interested in speed and security, I'd recommend installing the `simplejson` module yourself. Python's `json` module, as of 2.6, is an older version of `simplejson` that doesn't have all the speed and security improvements of the latest version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> the_dump=json.dumps("['foo', {'bar':['baz', null, 1.0, 2]}]")
```

You're asking it to json encode a string, so it's not surprising that you get a string back when you decode. Try instead:

```
>>> the_dump=json.dumps(['foo', {'bar':['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}])
```